# How to create new section and move row to it with animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have this code in tableviewdidSelectRow :

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:tableView.numberOfSections] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:indexPath toIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:tableView.numberOfSections ]];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

After endUpdates I'm getting crash with:

> cannot move a row into a newly inserted section

Where is my mistake? How to create new section and move row to it with animation so ?

Answer (score 0):

It is better late, than never, for next generation, my solution was to use deleteRow + insertRow instead of moveRow..., like this code:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];

[self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:newSectionNum]
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:oldIndexPath]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

[self.tableView endUpdates];
```